# Seaborn and mplcursors

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot, mplcursors

I have some data that I want to plot on a scatter chart, and display the associated label for each point. The data looks like

```
xlist=[1,2,3,4]
ylist=[2,3,4,5]
labels=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I can plot using Seaborn and tried to use mplcursor, but the displayed labels are the x and y instead of labels.

```
sns.scatterplot(x, y)
mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
```

How can I make it display the labels, instead of `(x, y)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to read [the `mplcursors` documentation](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#customization) and copy the example on that matter from it to your code. Let me do that for you:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import mplcursors

xlist=[1,2,3,4]
ylist=[2,3,4,5]
labels=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

sns.scatterplot(xlist, ylist)

cursor = mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
cursor.connect(
    "add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text(labels[sel.target.index]))

plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm sorry - I downvoted as I thought this didn't work but realize one needs to add `%matplotlib notebook` and it does. Sorry!

Comment: @jdc if that's the case, please remove the DV and UV instead.