# mplcursors with seaborn and multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, mplcursors

I am trying to use mplcursors when plotting data from multiple pandas DataFrames (or from multiple subsets of a single DataFrame).
I have read the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63051740/3460390) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55821124/3460390), as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59800059/3460390), which is somewhat redundent with the first one.
I am able to adapt the code of the [documentation on Extracting data and labels from a DataFrame](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/dataframe.html) to using seaborn with a *single* DataFrame, i.e. the following works fine:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
from pandas import DataFrame
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

df = DataFrame(
    [("Alice", 163, 54),
     ("Bob", 174, 67),
     ("Charlie", 177, 73),
     ("Diane", 168, 57)],
    columns=["name", "height", "weight"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="height", y="weight", ax=ax)

mplcursors.cursor().connect("add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text(df["name"][sel.index]))
```

The code of the answer to the first question, which is for multiple DataFrames, but without using seaborn, also works fine for me. However, if I try to adapt it to make it work with seaborn, then no cursor is produced. Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
from pandas import DataFrame
import seaborn as sns

df = DataFrame([("Alice", 163, 54), ("Bob", 174, 67), ("Charlie", 177, 73), ("Diane", 168, 57)], columns=["name", "height", "weight"])
df1 = DataFrame([("Alice1", 140, 50), ("Bob1", 179, 60), ("Charlie1", 120, 70), ("Diane1", 122, 60)], columns=["name", "height", "weight"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
# scat = ax.scatter(df["height"], df["weight"])# from the original answer
# scat1 = ax.scatter(df1["height"], df1["weight"])# from the original answer
scat = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="height", y="weight")# my version
scat1 = sns.scatterplot(data=df1, x="height", y="weight")# my version
scat.annotation_names = [f'{n}\nh: {h}' for n, h in zip(df["name"], df["height"])]
scat1.annotation_names = [f'{n}\nw: {w}' for n, w in zip(df1["name"], df1["weight"])]

cursor = mplcursors.cursor([scat, scat1], hover=True)
cursor.connect("add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text(sel.artist.annotation_names[sel.target.index]))
```

I'm using mplcursors version 0.5.1 and seaborn version 0.11.2 in Jupyter, with the `%matplotlib notebook` backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib's `ax.scatter` returns the graphical elements it created. Seaborn, on the other hand, returns the `ax` (subplot) on which the plot was created. (Many seaborn functions create a lot of different types of graphical elements).

In this case, the elements are stored in `ax.collections[0]` for the first call, and `ax.collections[1]` for the second.  Assigning these to the `scat` and `scat1` variables mimics the matplotlib approach.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
from pandas import DataFrame
import seaborn as sns

df = DataFrame([("Alice", 163, 54), ("Bob", 174, 67), ("Charlie", 177, 73), ("Diane", 168, 57)], columns=["name", "height", "weight"])
df1 = DataFrame([("Alice1", 140, 50), ("Bob1", 179, 60), ("Charlie1", 120, 70), ("Diane1", 122, 60)], columns=["name", "height", "weight"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="height", y="weight", ax=ax)
sns.scatterplot(data=df1, x="height", y="weight", ax=ax)
scat = ax.collections[0]
scat1 = ax.collections[1]
scat.annotation_names = [f'{n}\nh: {h}' for n, h in zip(df["name"], df["height"])]
scat1.annotation_names = [f'{n}\nw: {w}' for n, w in zip(df1["name"], df1["weight"])]

cursor = mplcursors.cursor([scat, scat1], hover=True)
cursor.connect("add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text(sel.artist.annotation_names[sel.target.index]))
plt.show()
```

[image: mplcursors with seaborn sns.scatterplot]

Comment: Oh I see, so that's what I missed. It works, thank you so much!